# More "efficient" system than powers of 2?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, binary

Based on the following riddle I have a mathematical question:

> A salesman sells two kinds of candy that look alike very much except
>   that one kind is 1 gram heavier than the other one. The salesman has
>   **11** bags of candy. Each bag contains either one kind of candy, or the
>   other, so no mix. Each bag contains **1000** pieces of candy.
>
> He want to use his scale only once and he wants to know what kind of
>   candy each of the bags contains. How does he solve this?

$2^{10}$ yields 1024, which is a problem since each bag contains maximum 1000 pieces of candy. However, by splitting the first piece of candy in half a solution can be found: $\frac{1}{2}$ from the first bag, 1 from the second, 2 from the third, 4 from the fourth etc.

**Now my question is this:** are there any solutions to this riddle that don't force us to split the candy? My intuition says no, but how to prove?

For example: how can we we sure that possibilities like 100, 101, 102, 104, 108, 116 etc... don´t work in principle? (of course you can show it by calculating all possibilities, but that's not elegant)

**Edit**
Most elegant solution so far:
{1000-0, 1000-1, 1000-2, 1000-4,...,1000-512}

Comment: Does the salesperson know the weight of the 'normal' candy?  Given the given solution, I think the person would have to.  Or is the weight a whole number of grams maybe?  Something is nmissing here ...

Comment: Weight of light candy is known

Comment: Well ... then I think your solution works ...

Comment: @Bram28 It doesn't because $356=132+116+108$.

Comment: @ChrisCulter Hmm, and therefore .. sorry, I don;t see it.  Because you can only have 1 bag with strange candy, not 3 ... what am I missing here?

Comment: @Bram28:  you are missing that there might be any number of bags with bad candy, not just one.

Comment: @RossMillikan Duh!  (slaps forehead hard!) :P

Comment: How do you rate efficiency ???

Comment: @YvesDaoust In the sense that it can provide a solution in integers to the riddle while a series of powers of 2 cannot.

Answer (score 5):

Yes! There are more efficient answers. Here is one, from https://oeis.org/A096858: $$\{285,433,510,550,570,581,587,590,592,593,594\}$$
This set of $11$ positive integers has the property that all $2^{11}$ of its subset sums are unique.

You can find out more by researching sets with unique subset sums and the Conway-Guy sequence. OEIS has a couple good links to start with.

Comment: Thanks! Isn´t this the only solution then?

Comment: I suspect there are other solutions, although I don't know how to generate them.

Comment: In what way is this "more efficient" ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust The maximum of the set is lesser than the powers of $2$, so it serves as a solution to the puzzle, where each number must be $\leq 1000$. (On the other hand, one pays a price: the sum of the set is greater.)